# Editor created buttons stop working in my uwp app

Tags: c#, uwp

I have created the following piece of code that gets executed when I press an existing button made with the editor

```
var test = new TextBlock();
test.Text = "meep!";
test.Margin = new Thickness(50, 50, 100, 100);
FrontPage.Children.Add(test);
```

the code itself is working but after the "meep!" has been added to the screen all buttons created by the editor stop working, how do I fix this?

Comment: ...this is only a small partion of the code, but can it be the case that it works, but it adds the TextBlock to the same position every time, so you don't see that a new TextBlock was added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are putting the [`Button`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.button) element inside a [`Grid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid) named `FrontPage` as follows, and invoke the above code snippet in button click event handle. Then after you clicking the button, the [`TextBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock) will be added to the application view but the button cannot be clicked again.

```
<Grid x:Name="FrontPage" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
   <Button
       x:Name="btnaddtext"
       Margin="117,289,0,0"
       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       VerticalAlignment="Top"
       Click="btnaddtext_Click"
       Content="Button" /> 
</Grid>
```

The reason is that if you didn't set the size for the `TextBlock`, it will stretch to fill the `Grid`, so that the `TextBlock` will cover the `Button` element that inside the `Grid` and it will not be clickable. `TextBlock` may be glassy so that  you can still see the `Button` but cannot access. If you change `TextBlock` to `TextBox` and update the background color you may see the effects.

You have many ways to resolve this, for example, set `Height` and `Width` for the `TextBlock` as follows:

```
var test = new TextBlock();
test.Text = "meep!";
test.Height = 100;
test.Width = 100;
test.Margin = new Thickness(50, 50, 100, 100);
FrontPage.Children.Add(test);
```

Or change a parent layout panel, for example, to a [`StackPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.stackpanel).

```
<StackPanel x:Name="FrontPage" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
   <Button
       x:Name="btnaddtext"
       Margin="117,289,0,0"
       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       VerticalAlignment="Top"
       Click="btnaddtext_Click"
       Content="Button" /> 
</StackPanel>
```

There're also other ways. To use which way depends on your requirements and the layout. More details about layout panel please reference [layout panels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/layout-panels).

Comment: The problem was indeed that the Textblock was filling the enitre page and thus overlapping the buttons, setting width and height fixed this. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I think you foget to add the TextBlock's algment.

You can try add the property to TextBlock and the code is below.

```
        var test = new TextBlock()
        {
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
        };
        test.Text = "meep!";
        test.Margin = new Thickness(50, 50, 100, 100);
        FrontPage.Children.Add(test);
```

But I think I cant care all what you mean and my code can work.

And you should know that TextBlock cant be edit. The TextBlock only can show the text.